# ExtJS 4: Dropdown button in menu trouble

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have panel with some elements (second dropdown button) in dropdown button menu.
When I click second dropdown button, main menu is closing.
Here is my code:

Create 1st level dropdown button

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Click me',
            margin: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            menu: getMenu()
        });
    });
```

Cretae menu for 1st level

```
    function getMenu() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            plain: true,
            items: [
                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    width: 500,
                    height: 100,
                    bodyPadding: 5,
                    items: [
                        getFirstElement(),
                        getSecondElement()
                    ]
                })
            ]
        });
    }
```

Create some element

```
    function getFirstElement() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
            fieldLabel: 'Date',
            value: null,
            labelWidth: 50,
            width: 150,
            padding: 5
        });
    }
```

Create 2nd level dropdown button

```
    function getSecondElement() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Select',
            menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                plain: true,
                items: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        width: 500,
                        height: 100,
                        bodyPadding: 5,
                        items: [
                            {
                                html: '1'
                            },
                            {
                                html: '2'
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a config option on menu called `allowOtherMenus`. Setting that to true will allow other menu's to be displayed at the same time as the menu with config option set.

So, your getSecondElement function becomes:

```
function getSecondElement() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Select',
            menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {                
                allowOtherMenus: true,
                plain: true,
                items: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        width: 500,
                        height: 100,
                        bodyPadding: 5,
                        items: [
                            {
                                html: '1'
                            },
                            {
                                html: '2'
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        });
    }
```

Your example working with multiple menus can be found in this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SEVCe/

Documentation regarding that property can be found  in the Sencha [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-cfg-allowOtherMenus).